# Login System using JSP - forgot password, using sql database?

Tags: java, jsp, frameworks, authentication

I am a traditional .NET developer... now I have to create a web application using JSP.

Is there some sort of framework that handles all the login stuff for me?

- Register users (and securely store in database using best practices)
- forgot password functionality
- session tracking (aka make sure only a logged in user can see the page)

Like I said, I'm mostly familiar with .NET Membership. I'm researching Spring, Struts, and Hibernate but am not sure the pros/cons of each yet.

If you had to create this simple web application using JSP how would you go about it?

Thanks for your help :-)

-Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/).

> Spring Security is a powerful and highly customizable authentication and access-control framework.

Comment: Haha, you beat me to it by a few seconds. Upvoting just because I agree.

Comment: I went through and did a bunch of tutorials. Spring Security has a lot of great features. If I decide to make a tutorial of my own I'll post it

Comment: Nice, I would be very interested in one.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer? No.

There are however, very many security frameworks that you can customize to fit your needs. I would recommend looking at [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) as a good all-around tool that should fit your needs.